# Firebase Not Sending Notifications from Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm having an issue in regards to sending push notifications to an android device from the Firebase console. [Specifically, Firebase is not attempting to send the notification.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09pHU.png) The linked image shows what I see from the console upon sending the notification (completed status, delivery date that corresponds with the time I sent it, but nothing actually sent).

I initially discovered this problem in my own app, but moved on to testing the problem with [Firebase's demonstration app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging), but to no avail. I can fetch FCM Registration Tokens without issue, so there is a connection to Firebase. I'm primarily testing on an emulator in Android Studio with API 25, but I've also tested on emulators with APIs 17 and 23 as well as personal android devices with APIs 17 and 23. I've tried a variety of Firebase/Google Play versions ranging from 9.0.2 to the current 10.0.1. I also haven't changed any code in the Firebase demo app (other than dependencies in build.gradle and the manifest in attempts to solve my problem).

What makes this issue even stranger is that these notifications eventually send, but it takes an abnormally long amount of time and it's always after the app/emulator has been closed, so I've never actually seen them. Sometimes it takes a few hours, but oftentimes it's not until the following day when I look at the console and see that it sent. Initially I chalked this up to a simple delay, but I've sent 50+ test notifications over the past week and a half and all of them have had this problem.

This is what the only files I made any changes to currently look like (the most recent test notification was sent to an emulator with API 25):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!-- [START fcm_default_icon] -->
    <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
         notification message.-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    <!-- [END fcm_default_icon] -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
    <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
</application>
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help or insight anybody could provide would be much appreicated. Thanks!

EDIT 1:

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

Upon request, here are the service implementations. It should be noted that they are unchanged from the stock version linked in paragraph 2.

```
/**
* Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
 // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
    * Persist token to third-party servers.
    *
    * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
    * maintained by your application.
    *
    * @param token The new token.
    */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
*/

package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. 
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be:
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I should add that onMessageReceived is never triggered.

Comment: Post your service implementations, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @HristoStoyanov I've added it, although I should note that it is no different from the stock version that I linked.

Comment: Why are you using older version of the library , try with 10.0.1

Comment: @HristoStoyanov 10.0.1 doesn't work with API 25, only API 23 (which I tried, and that was unsuccessful)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @MohammadYahia Unfortunately not. Still have no idea what was wrong. I had to create a custom messaging protocol instead.

Comment: From what I knew, notifications are not sent to simulators. You have to test on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

In your dependencies in build.gradle add the following:

```
//Used for firebase services
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
```

EDIT:

Normally with the following in your app's build.gradle

```
//Used for firebase services 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' 
//Used for push notification services 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

And the following in your root's build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

And the google-services.json that you have generated giving your package name and the sha1 key you should be able to receive push notifications sent from firebase. Check again if you have copied the correct **sha1** key and not the *sha256* nor the *mda5* key

Comment: Did you copy the generated google-services.json in your app folder?

Comment: I did, that was one of the first things I looked for

Comment: Your edit was helpful, as I had not considered an issue with the SHA1 key. Although I checked it out and unfortunately, this also was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Working with IOS device.
My issue was that I didn't upload APNs file in Firebase Console.

Go to Firebase Console:
--> Settings
--> Project Settings
--> Cloud Messaging
--> iOS app configuration
--> Upload APNs